# How to set emoji by unicode in a textview?

Tags: android, unicode, textview, encode, emoji

Hi I'd like to do the following:

```
??? unicode = U+1F60A
String emoji = getEmojiByUnicode(unicode)
String text = "So happy "
textview.setText(text + emoji);
```

to get this in my textview:

> So happy

How can I implement `getEmojiByUnicode(unicode)`?

What type should the `unicode` variable be? (String, char, int?)

Please note that I do NOT want to use Drawables!

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Found a solution:

In my unicode I replaced '**U+**' by '**0x**'

Example: replace '**U+1F60A**' by '**0x1F60A**'

This way I got an 'int' like

```
int unicode = 0x1F60A;
```

Which can be used with

```
public String getEmojiByUnicode(int unicode){
    return new String(Character.toChars(unicode));
}
```

So Textview displays  without Drawable

Try it with http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Comment: works on 5.1 but on 4.4.4 i get a ? for my emoji string

Comment: Is it possible to do this in strings.xml file ?

Comment: @user1232726, This will depend on the user's phone including the emoji being used.

Comment: Can u please help to convert this "5794d5f7895fa10a8f8e1357" into the EMOJI.. @GilbertGiesbert ..Thanks...

Comment: What if I have the unicode in the form of string? How do I convert it into integer? Parsing makes in invalid as it removes 'F' from it.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with 32 bit Unicode, like U+1F1EF U+1F1F2. This value is outside the integer boundaries.

Comment: NOte: For Kotlin
> fun getEmoji(unicode: Int): String {
        return String(Character.toChars(unicode))
    }

Answer (score 62):

You can directly use Emojis in string resources by using the decimal code like this:

```
&#128522;
```

for example:

```
<string name="emoji">I am happy &#128522;</>
```

Comment: This is a good answer; to find the decimal code of an emoji, you can use something like https://www.quackit.com/character_sets/emoji/

Comment: i don't find the x necessary

Comment: Error while build: Character reference "&#

Comment: @hmac I've rolled back the answer, removed mentions of `x`

Answer (score 7):

Note: For Kotlin

```
fun getEmoji(unicode: Int): String {
    return String(Character.toChars(unicode))
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think I found the most straightforward solution. In my case, I wanted to add a fire () emoji to one of the chips in a chip group. I simply went to the [Emojipedia Fire Entry](https://emojipedia.org/fire/)<sup>1</sup>, clicked on the `copy` button just below the emoji meaning, and literally just pasted it into my Kotlin code. Here is a code snippet of how it looked like after pasting.

```
val chip = Chip(context)
chip.text = "\uD83D\uDD25 New"
```

Here is how the code looks like once I run it on my device. I included the other chips as well ;

[image: An image sample of how the chip looks like in the device]

PS: I ran this on the latest version of Android Studio (Arctic Fox v. 2020.3.1). Results may differ with older versions.

*Footnote*

1. Emojipedia is a free encyclopedia that lists and provides meanings for all the emojis approved under the Unicode standard. You can always head out there for insightful emoji meanings and for other emoji needs.

Answer (score 5):

all of the credit to Kenneth Murerwa, whose answer solved my problem. just chiming in that just copy and paste what you get from the 'copy' button at https://emojipedia.org between good old quotation marks. Yeah, it's a noob point but hey, we're all noobs at the beggining

```
val emoji = "\uD83D\uDE00 \uD83D\uDC4C"
```

and then you can add it to whatever string you need. It renders on the phone screen fine, though it won't show up in a println

```
println("")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below:

Unicode : `uni-1F4A1`

*FYI, I am using Kotlin.*

**Create utility function as below:**

```
private fun getEmojiByUnicode(reactionCode: String): String {
        val code = reactionCode.substring(4).toInt(16)
        return String(Character.toChars(code))
}
```

Where `substring(4)` will be discarded `uni-` these 3 characters and you have `1F4A1`.

**Set Emoji into TextView:** (I am using ViewBinding in my Project)

```
mViewBinding.textViewEmoji.text = getEmojiByUnicode(data.Reaction)
```

For more details: [Integer.parseInt ("0x1F60A") ends with NumberformatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562198/integer-parseint0x1f60a-ends-up-with-numberformatexception)

Answer (score 0):

```
// example of unicode emoji - "U+1F4C1"
// other formats will return empty string
fun unicodeEmojiToHtmlEmoji(emoji: String): CharSequence {
    val inEmojiPrefix = "U+"
    val outEmojiPrefix = "&#x"
    val outEmojiSuffix = ";"
    return try {
        HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
            emoji.replace(
                inEmojiPrefix,
                outEmojiPrefix, true) + outEmojiSuffix,
            HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY
        )
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        ""
    }
}

// example of html emoji - "&#x1F4C1;"
// other formats will return empty string
fun htmlEmojiToUnicodeEmoji(emoji: String): CharSequence {
    val outEmojiPrefix = "U+"
    return if(emoji.isNotBlank()) outEmojiPrefix + emoji.codePointAt(0).let(Integer::toHexString) else ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, emoji Unicodes didn't work. So I just copied them and pasted them into my XML string and everything worked fine!