# adding emoji for android service keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

I have already looked at : [Add emoji to Android keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639800/add-emoji-to-android-keyboard)

But this is not exactly what I am seeking for.
I am making a service keyboard, not just for an app, I am unable to add emojis like an adapter. I don't want to make multiple rows like I have made for texts(qwerty) because the emojis are way too much and the experience will not be user friendly.I want the user experience like chat apps give, just swipe down the emojis till you find the desired one. I am basically trying to inflate a layout and set an adapter for it on click of key icon I have used in qwerty.xml. My approach might be wrong as well.
I am stuck because of this from quite a while now, if any one has got a solution to this, please do leave tips.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use popupwindow in your custom keyboard is the best way to solve it. make a popupwindow and draw it listview combined each of views( inside list view) with a gridview. this popupwindow fall in over a keyboard and you can use it for emoji and it is easy to come back to your keyboard.