# Include emoji in button string

Tags: android, emoji

I am trying to have a button with an emoji character within the text string for that button. I know there is a way to do this in iOS, is there a way to do this in Android?

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you use `Spannable` to display images inline with text (which is similar to the iOS 'NSAttributedString` concept, I believe).

This should work for `TextView` `Button` and `EditText` and there are many references / examples available, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer over here: 
[how set emoji by unicode in a textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893796/how-set-emoji-by-unicode-in-a-textview)

You have to use unicodes unlike in iOS where you can add them directly