# Android Yes No Button emoji

Tags: android, emoji, feedback, submit-button, user-feedback

How can I set emoji in yes no button and submit button ?
I'm going to create a feedback app.

[I need to create a form like this :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31KRL.png)

Comment: Why don't you try by yourself. Try to google it and move a step. Then we can help you.

Comment: You basically want a custom `Switch`. I'm confident you can use Google for that.

Comment: Use TextView and  create custom drawable for ovel shape and set this drawble to background of textview and use drwableLeft for set smiley icon on textview.... its work enjoy

Comment: Actually , I'm new to android. I need More support from you guys.

Comment: Is there any option to apply templates in android?

Comment: for future users refer answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26894146/884674

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These seem like a Buttons with custom background and a drawable. 
Simply create a Button

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/yes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/emoji"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/emoji"
            android:background="@drawable/yes_background"
            android:text="@string/yes" />
```

And then create a drawable in your drawables folder, named "yes_background", as such

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
</selector>
```

In your drawable folders, create another three drawables, for "button_selected", "button_pressed", "button_normal", and colour them in whichever you would like.
For example, "button_selected" could be:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
 </shape>
```

Do the same for the no button and the submit button.