# Integer.parseInt("0x1F60A") ends up with NumberformatException

Tags: java, android, emoji, numberformatexception

I try to get the emoji code inside a long string from database, in this format: **0x1F60A** ... So I can access the code but it will be a **String**.

At first, I tried to cast the variable by doing `tv.setText(beforeEmo + getEmijoByUnicode((int)emoKind));` but Android Studio hints: "cannot cast 'java.lang.String' to int"...

The **getEmijoByUnicode** method is:

```
public String getEmijoByUnicode(int unicode) {
    return new String(Character.toChars(unicode));
}
```

So I tried this one:

```
tv.setText(beforeEmo + getEmijoByUnicode(Integer.parseInt(emoKind)));
```

but it crashes with NumberFormatError. Is there any way to make the emoji appear in my text?

Comment: Maybe you meant `0x1F60A` without quotes? Otherwise, you just have a string. Otherwise, `parseInt` accepts a radix parameter of 16

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39850130/4723795

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
Integer.parseInt("1F60A", 16);
```

or

```
Long.parseLong("1F60A", 16);
```

to convert the string to int or long. So you have to get rid of the "0x", like this

```
getEmijoByUnicode(Integer.parseInt(emoKind.substring(2), 16));
```