# Put emoji code in a string

Tags: android

I am using this emoji library

https://github.com/hani-momanii/SuperNova-Emoji

This library has a custom textview which can render emojis.  How do I set text of that textview so it displays emojis ?

For example I tried this and it did not work :

```
String happy = " Feeling happy U+1F601 ";
emojitextview.setText(happy);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how set emoji by unicode in android textview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893796/how-set-emoji-by-unicode-in-android-textview)

Answer (score 3):

Switch out the 'U+' for '0x':

```
int unicode = 0x1F601;

String happy = "Feeling happy " + getEmojiByUnicode(unicode);
```

And put it through a helper function:

```
public String getEmojiByUnicode(int unicode){
    return new String(Character.toChars(unicode));
}
```

p.s. if it still doesn't work, you may have to set the textView to use a typeface that supports emoji characters

from:
[how set emoji by unicode in android textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893796/how-set-emoji-by-unicode-in-android-textview)