# Adding multiple smiles in TextView using ImageSpan

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring, spannable

I am trying to add multiple smiles in textview using this code.
This is my TextView.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:bufferType="spannable" />
```

And this is add smiley function.

```
public void addSmily() {
        int resource  = R.drawable.smily ;

        Spannable spannable = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(" ");

        Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, resource);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 40);
        ImageSpan smilySpan = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);

        spannable.setSpan(smilySpan, spannable.length()-1, spannable.length(), 0);

        sendText.append(spannable);
}
```

Smiles are adding perfectly but the problem is when I add lots of smiles did not fit in a single line then the first line of smiles become invisible and they start from the 2nd line.

[image: App Privew]
This is what happening. Plz, someone help me.

Comment: Why adding smiley as image?. Did you try to add smiley as unicode?

Comment: No, I did not try Unicode

Comment: Please, check out the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

Try this inside your button:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("abc");

Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(your_activity.this, R.drawable.your_smiley_drawable);
d.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 40);
ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

edittext.append(ss);
```

**Note:** Also, EditText's inputtype must be textMultiline.

Try it, Works in my lap, Let's Hope it helps to you too.

Comment: can you explain whats the difference between using " single space " and "abc" in SpannableString?

Comment: There is no difference, anything inside the double-quotes("") is treated as String, If you give single-space, You are writing a "space character" which will also be treated as a String. @MuhammadAsim Check out more: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString

Answer (score 1):

You can also set smiley by unicode in textview.

[how set emoji by unicode in a textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893796/how-set-emoji-by-unicode-in-a-textview)

```
int unicode = 0x1F60A;
```

Which can be used with

```
public String getEmojiByUnicode(int unicode){
    return new String(Character.toChars(unicode));
}
```

So Textview displays  without Drawable

Try it with http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Hope it may help you.