# How do I add emoticons to textview and edittext in android studio?

Tags: android

I have tried the methods posted online, but they use external libraries. Is there a way to do it natively?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26894146/8202132 This link might help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set emoji by unicode in a textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893796/how-to-set-emoji-by-unicode-in-a-textview)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. Look at this implementation. There's a function which converts the unicode emoji into char so you can append it to the string being displayed in your textview/edittext.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHzhWbmdkWM

```
        # This is in oncreate

          int unicode=0x1F600;
          String emoji= getEmoji(unicode);

        # Our new function

          public String getEmoji(int uni)
          {
              return new String(Character.toChars(uni));
          }
```