# Single letter or emojis are not inserting in Database with a post request API from android App

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit2

I am developing an app where users can post text, img or video. Everything working fine. But sometimes it's giving me the error `Unprocessable Content`, when I want to post a single letter or emoji.

```
ERROR:: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=422, message=Unprocessable Content, url=http://myUrl.com}
```

[image: please see the attched img]

**My RetrofitBuiler Object:**

```
 var gson: Gson = GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S")
        .create()

    private var httpClient =
        OkHttpClient.Builder().retryOnConnectionFailure(true).connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()

    private val retrofit: Retrofit by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(getBaseUrl())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addConverterFactory(NullConvertfactory()).client(httpClient).build()
    }

    val API_SERVICE: FansApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(FansApiService::class.java)

    }
```

**APi InterFace:**

```
@Headers("Accept:application/json")
@Multipart
@POST("endurlHere")
fun createPost(
    @Header("Authorization") token: String,
    @Part("text_content") text_content: RequestBody,
    @Part imageList: List<MultipartBody.Part>
): Call<CreatePostResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode emoji / or any non textual content for that matter in "UNICODE". Send them to server as UNICODE string and when displaying them decode them back.
[Here's the reference link that can help you get started.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893796/how-to-set-emoji-by-unicode-in-a-textview)

Comment: Emojis are sent to the server.the problem occurs when I try to send only a single emoji(no text or any thing,just a emoji)

Comment: This also happens as well as for just a  single letter